# Match text except comma

Tags: r, grepl

I have a string vector of symptoms, possibly multiple symptoms which are separated by commas, say:

`x <- c('throat dry, muscles a bit painful', 'throat is a bit painful', 'throat pain, chest tightness', 'throatpain')`

I'd like to use `grepl` or other regex function to return TRUE if "throat pain" or any slight variation is matched. In the example vector above, the result should be `FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for your example. Look for "throat", then "anything but comma 0 or more times", then "pain".

```
library(stringr)

str_detect(x, "throat[^,]{0,}pain")

[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: `[^,]{0,}` => `[^,]*`

Answer (score 2):

Does this work: Using negative lookbehind.

```
grepl('throat[A-z\\s]*(,?<|)pain.*', x, perl = 1)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```